# Glueing Sheaves.

Tags: sheaf-theory

I have two questions about glueing sheaves. See Hartshorne Ch2 Ex1.22.

Let X be a topological space, let $\{U_i\}$ be an open cover of X, and suppose we are given for each $i$ a sheaf $\mathcal{F}_i$ on $U_i$, and for each $i,j$ an isomorphism of sheaves $\phi_{ij}:\mathcal{F}_i\mid_{U_i\cap U_j}\to\mathcal{F}_j\mid_{U_i\cap U_j}$,
such that (1) for each $i$, $\phi_{ii}=$ id, and (2) for each $i,j,k$, $\phi_{ik}=\phi_{jk}\phi_{ij}$ on $U_i\cap U_j\cap U_k$.
Then there exists there exists a unique sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on X, together with isomorphisms $\psi_i:\mathcal{F}\mid_{U_i}\to\mathcal{F}_i$ such that for each $i,j$, $\psi_j=\phi_{ij}\psi_i$ on $U_i\cap U_j$.

My questions are:

1. Is the assumption that $\{U_i\}$ is covering X is necessary? I mean we could construct $\mathcal{F}$ without it.
2. I have no idea of where to use the above property (2) in the process of construction.
   If V is a open set of X, a section of $\mathcal{F}(V)$ will be represented by $<s_i>$ such that for each $i$, $s_i \in \mathcal{F}_i(U_i\cap V)$ and for each $i,j$, $\phi_{ij}(s_i\mid _{U_i\cap U_j\cap V})=s_j\mid _{U_i\cap U_j\cap V}$.
   I think I could prove $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies sheaf properties and $\psi$ is commutative without the assumption.

Comment: 1. If $\{U_i\}$ is not a covering of $X$, then you will construct a sheaf on $\bigcup U_i$. Think about functions, if you have functions $f_i$ on each $U_i$, then (under some conditions) you can glue them, but you won't have a function on the whole $X$ if the $U_i$ do not cover $X$. 
2. Yes it is necessary. I can't tell you what won't work without because it may depend on you construction but if you show me your attempt to prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is well-defined sheaf without, I may point you where is the mistake.

Comment: But note that if you have a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ with isomorphisms $\psi_i:\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}\to\mathcal{F}_i$ on each $U_i$, then you will have the cocycle condition (2). In other words, if you already have the conclusion, then the conditions (1) and (2) holds, so if you have (1) but not (2) you cannot have the conclusion.

Comment: I found the mistake! The last comment helps me a lot. I didn't give the proper proof of  $\psi_i$'s injectivity. Now I've solved it. Thanks!